# How do I solve this program, trying to make a simple todo project in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm still learning as you may see in my next code. I'm trying to make a simple todo project without any css. When I click on the add button the text gets added to array, but it doesnt get displayed. I get an error: https://ibb.co/zRGmykC. I'm pretty sure this is easy for someone with some experience but I need your help. The code is on the link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-agera5?file=src/index.js

Answer (score -1):

You set todos as an array in App.js on line 6, however, when you call the addTodo function, you set todos as an object.

```
    let newTodos = { id, text };
```

Then, in your TodoList, you try to map the results of todos, but once it's been cast as an object, map will no longer work, because map is a method only available to arrays.

Instead, you should create a temporary Array and assign it to a destructured array of your todos. You can then push your new todo into that array and then set your todos state to that temporary array.

```
  const addTodo = (text) => {
    let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    const tempArray = [...todos];
    tempArray.push({ id, text });
    setTodos(tempArray);
  };
```

Then, in your TodoList, you need to map your key and value as todo.id and todo.text

```
import React from 'react';

const TodoList = ({ todos }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <div key={todo.id}>{todo.text}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

You were also missing a few react imports. Make sure even if you're importing {useState} you're also importing React. Here's an example of what the top of your Form should look like:

`import React, { useState } from 'react';`

Comment: I just went trough my code 20 times after i posted the question here and I found out where I messed up, but really thanks a lot. People like you make this world a better place.